# Bound on Rayleigh quotient on $H^{1}_{\text{per}}[0,1]^{n}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, periodic-functions, maximum-principle

Let $Q=[0,1]^{n}$. Define a $Q$-periodic function as follows:

> A function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{C}$ is said to be **$Q$-periodic** if for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and any $z\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}$, it holds that
>
> $$f(x+z)=f(x)$$

Consider the (Hilbert) space $H^{1}_{\text{per}}(Q)$ of $Q$-periodic functions that are $H^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ (i.e. $H^{1}$ on any compact), endowed with the following hermitian product:

$$(u,v)\mapsto (u,v)_{1,Q}:= \int_{Q}\nabla u\cdot\nabla \overline{v}+\int_{Q}u\overline{v}$$

We denote $\Vert u\Vert_{H^{1}_{\text{per}}(Q)}:=(u,u)_{1,Q}^{1/2}$. Similarly, we consider the (Hilbert) space $L^{2}_{\text{per}}(Q)$ of $Q$-periodic functions that are $L^{2}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$, endowed with the following hermitian product:

$$(u,v)\mapsto (u,v)_{0,Q}:=\int_{Q}u\overline{v}\hspace{1em}\text{ and }\hspace{1em}\Vert u\Vert_{L^{2}_{\text{per}}(Q)}:=(u,u)_{0,Q}^{1/2}$$

I want to bound the following quantity:

$$\min_{W_{m}\subset H^{1}_{\text{per}}(Q)}\max_{\substack{u\in W_{m}\\ \Vert u\Vert_{L^{2}_{\text{per}}(Q)}=1}}\int_{Q}\nabla u\cdot\nabla\bar{u}$$

where $W_{m}$ denotes any $m$-dimensional subspace of $H^{1}_{\text{per}}(Q)$.

I thought of the laplacian eigenvalues, but the functions are not in $H^{1}_{0}(Q)$. How can we exploit the periodicity here?

Any help is appreciated (hints are good of course).

Comment: The expression gives you the $m$-th eigenvalue of the Laplacian acting on $[0,1]^n$ with periodic boundary conditions. The eigenfunctions are precisely the characters $e^{2\pi i \vec{n} \cdot \vec{x}}$ where $\vec{n} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with corresponding eigenvalues $-(2\pi)^2 ||\vec{n}||_2^2$. From this you can estimate the $m$-th eigenvalue and the number of eigenvalues $\leq N$ by analyzing a lattice count problem.

Comment: @levap Sure, I should have thought about that. Thanks a lot! Yet, I did not get what you mean by Your last sentence. However, I only need to know that it is finite, so your argument gives me that.

Comment: This expression gives you the eigenvalues but doesn't tell us what is their multiplicity. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then the multiplicity of $\lambda$ is determined by the number of integer vectors $\vec{n}$ that lie on the sphere of radius $\frac{\sqrt{-\lambda}}{2\pi}$ (this is the same as the number of ways to write $\frac{-\lambda}{4\pi^2}$ as a sum of $n$ squares of integers). Similarly, the number of eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) $\leq N$ is the number of integer lattice points contained inside a ball of radius $\frac{\sqrt{N}}{2\pi}$.

Comment: @levap Thank you. The reason that this Laplacian on this domain has a discrete spectrum is a classical consequence of Lax-Milgram + Rellich ensuring a compact resolvent. Is that right ? Hence the expression is finite whatever $m$. So, if I allow my bound to potentially depend on $m$, I have a bound for any $m$, isn'it ?

Comment: Well, since this is one of the rare cases that are symmetric enough to be solved explicitly, I would say that the reason is simply because you can calculate the spectrum and obtain an orthonormal basis of eigenvalues. The fancy tools are more relevant for general elliptic operators. What is less trivial is the minmax principle.

Comment: @levap I see... I do not have all the properties and reflexes in memory yet. Maybe is it still using fancy tools, but would it be possible to prove that I can apply the min max by proving that the inverse of the operator is compact (if so)?

Comment: I'm not sure. Usually one proves that $L - \lambda I$ is invertible with compact inverse, then uses the spectral theorem to deduce the existence of an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions and then uses the basis to prove the minimax principle. Since you have an explicit orthonormal basis in this case, I can't see how this will help.

Comment: @levap If I correctly get your point, I just have to prove that $L-\lambda I$ is invertible with compact inverse for some $\lambda$, which is due to Lax-Milgram + Rellich, no ? I am kind of lost. We have an explicit formula for eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. We want to prove that the spectrum is discrete. These arguments combined implies that the eigenvalues are given by the min-max principle ?

Comment: No, my point is that you don't need to prove that the spectrum is discrete - you already know it is.

Comment: @levap Thanks for your help, I got it !